# Spring 3 MVC query not executing after few calls

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am making a Spring 3 MVC Hibernate web application.The Problem i am facing is the app works properly but the problem arises when i call more then 6 or 7 database calls.Means trying to access data by executing few query.The first 6 to 7 queries are executed but after that.the queries stop executing means no response at all the app is dead. Very weird situation. i am pasting the servelet xml the service,implementation controller and dao please guide me where i am going wrong searching but still no solution

```
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/MyData/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Spring Database DataSource -->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/health" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="***" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="***" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 3 Session Factory  -->

    <beans:bean id="enversListener" class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.***.model"/>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                  <beans:prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</beans:prop>
                  <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</beans:prop>
                  <beans:prop key="show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                  <beans:prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>

        <beans:property name="eventListeners">
          <beans:map>
               <beans:entry key="post-insert"><beans:ref local="enversListener" /></beans:entry>
               <beans:entry key="post-update"><beans:ref local="enversListener" /></beans:entry>
               <beans:entry key="post-delete"><beans:ref local="enversListener" /></beans:entry>
               <beans:entry key="pre-collection-update"><beans:ref local="enversListener" /></beans:entry>
               <beans:entry key="pre-collection-remove"><beans:ref local="enversListener" /></beans:entry>
               <beans:entry key="post-collection-recreate"><beans:ref local="enversListener" /></beans:entry>
         </beans:map>
      </beans:property>

    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Bean Defination -->
    <beans:bean id="userDao" class="com.***.DAO.UserDaoImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="packDao" class="com.***.DAO.PackageDaoImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="adminDao" class="com.***.DAO.AdminDaoImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="branchDao" class="com.***.DAO.BranchDaoImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="companyDao" class="com.***.DAO.CompanyDaoImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="SubpackDao" class="com.***.DAO.SubpackageDaoImpl"/>

    <!-- Services Bean -->
    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.***.services.UserServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="packageService" class="com.***.services.PackageServiceImpl"/>


</beans:beans>
```

1.The Controller class which receives the request and calls the service implementation.

```
@Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/PackageController")
    public class PackageController implements PackageService{

        private PackageService packService;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("packageService")
        public void setPackService(PackageService packService) {
            this.packService = packService;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/get_package_list",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json")
        public @ResponseBody String callgetPackageList(){
            System.out.println("Get the package list");
            List<Package> packageList = this.getPackageList();
            Iterator <Package> itTemp = packageList.iterator();
            JSONObject json=null;
            JSONArray json_data_array= new JSONArray();

            while(itTemp.hasNext())
            {
                Package packageTemp = itTemp.next();
                json = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    json.put("Id", packageTemp.getPackageId());
                    json.put("PackageName", packageTemp.getPackageName());
                    json_data_array.put(json);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            json = new JSONObject();
            try {
                json.put("Id", "custom");
                json.put("PackageName", "Customise Package");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            json_data_array.put(json);

            return json_data_array.toString();
        }
    @Override
        public List<Package> getPackageList() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return packService.getPackageList();
        }
    }
```

3.The Service Implementation where the dao method is called and transactional annotation applied.

```
public class PackageServiceImpl implements PackageService{

        private PackageDao packageDao;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("packDao")
        public void setPackageDao(PackageDao packageDao) {
            this.packageDao = packageDao;
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public List<Package> getPackageList() {
            return packageDao.getPackageList();
        }
    }
```

4.The Dao implementation where the actual query is written to execute the main problem lies in serviceimplementation and package i guess.

```
public class PackageDaoImpl implements PackageDao{

            private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
            private SubpackageDao subpack;

            @Autowired
            @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
            public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
                this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
            }

            @Override
            public List<Package> getPackageList() {

                Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
                List<Package> packageListTemp = null;
                Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Package.class);
                criteria.setFetchMode("subpackages", FetchMode.SELECT);
                packageListTemp = criteria.list();
                return packageListTemp;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the answer hope it helps to someone who stumbles upon the same problem as me
the root cause of the problem was

```
Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
```

as per the post related to [HibernateTransaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135204/hibernate-transaction-manager-configurations-in-spring) when we use openSession instead of getCurrentSession, session is opened outside of scope spring container. As result session was not close hence the app was not responding to the query calls.